# PHPUnit/Selenium - How to stop Google Chrome from showing a SSL security error

Tags: security, google-chrome, ssl, selenium, phpunit

I'm running my selenium tests on a server that doesn't have a valid security certificate.  So when I run the tests I have to click "Proceed Anyway" on the certificate error screen in order for my tests to start.  I'm trying to automate my tests, but can't because I have to manually click "Proceed Anyway" for each one of my tests.

Is there any way to disable the SSL error when starting Chrome for my automated tests?

Thanks,

John

Comment: Isn't an invalid security certificate pretty bad anyway?

Comment: @Arran Not if it's self signed for testing, or other internal use. I use self-signed certs for some of my dev machines when I want to have an encrypted connection, but I don't want to pay for a trusted cert.

Comment: Windows. I found the answer.  I needed to start the selenium server with -trustAllSSLCertificates argument. e.g. java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -trustAllSSLCertificates

Answer (score 3):

The process on Mac/Chrome is the following:

1. Load the site with the certificate in question, accept the warning
2. Click the lock with the X in the address bar, then the "Certificate Information" button
3. Drag the picture of the certificate to your desktop
4. Double click the *.cer file that is now on your desktop to install it in your Keychain
5. Per the instructions, choose the "login" keychain for current user or "system"
6. Click "Add"
7. Once the cert has been added, choose the appropriate keychain and then double click the certificate
8. Expand the "Trust" section, and for "When using this certificate" choose "Always Trust"

I don't have a Windows machine, but [this article for Chrome](http://www.poweradmin.com/help/sslhints/Chrome.aspx) references [this article for IE](http://www.poweradmin.com/help/sslhints/ie.aspx) on how to install the cert to your Windows Certificate Store.